# Ruby on Rails @model.id returns negative id after save and also differs from id in database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am doing some maintenance on a Ruby on Rails application running Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.5. The database used is MySQL.

I am encountering a very strange bug on one of my models. Before saving, the id is nil (since it hasn't been assigned yet by saving to db). Then, when I do @model.save it saves the record in the db, but when I call @model.id it returns a negative value (-294731885) instead of the id assigned to it in the db (4000235410).

To debug, I have added the following to my shopping_cart model:

```
before_save :print_object_before
after_save :print_object_after

def print_object_before
  logger.debug "ShoppingCartBeforeSave: " + self.inspect
end

def print_object_after
  logger.debug "ShoppingCartAfterSave: " + self.inspect
end
```

In my controller, I call:

```
@shopping_cart.save!
```

The output I get in the log is as follows:

```
ShoppingCartBeforeSave: #<ShoppingCart id: nil, user_id: 4000001127, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, currency_code: "zar", coupon_code: nil>
ShoppingCartAfterSave: #<ShoppingCart id: -294731885, user_id: 4000001127, created_at: "2012-09-25 12:02:05", updated_at: "2012-09-25 12:02:05", currency_code: "zar", coupon_code: nil>
```

What could possibly be the problem? There are no other before- or after-filters defined on the model. I thought I might have run out of id's on MySQL, but that is not the case since it still saves the record correctly (and with a positive id) in the database despite returning a different value in rails. (For information, in the migration for the model, id is defined as integer.)

Some more info: it seems like the value of the negative value keeps increasing (smaller negative), eg on one attempt id would contain -294731885 on next attempt it would contain -294731884, on next attempt it would contain -294731883, etc.

Comment: What is the data type of your `id` column?

Comment: As mentioned, it is defined as integer. Which, as I understand it, means that it defaults to integer(4).

Comment: Sorry, I missed that at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of this, but you might have an issue with the type of your `id` column, which seems to not be large enough to hold the numbers you're getting at. Maybe the issue is on the ruby side though. I cannot be sure since I don't have the right versions installed and not enough experience with relational databases. hope this helps !